# Facebook Graph API: "post to Fan Page" creates two post entries

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post to a Public Fan page via Graph API.
I have two different Facebook accounts that I use for my testing (let's call them "User1" and "User2").

Here are the steps:

1. Send Graph API POST request:
   https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed?message=MESSAGE&access_token=USER1_TOKEN
2. Log-in as "User1" and navigate to Fan Page.

   **Result:** two identical MESSAGE records on Page wall.
3. Log-in as "User2" and navigate to Fan Page.

   **Result:** "User2" sees only one post record (without paperclip).
4. Get Page feed via Graph API get request: https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed?access_token=USER1_TOKEN

   **Result:** FB returns only one post record.

Does anyone know why I see two records in Step 2?
I didn't find anything in FB Dev documentation...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't reproduce that behaviour at all, only one post appears - are you sure there's nothing running on your machine which is making a second request to the API?

Comment: Nothing... Very strange thing: I tried this scenario using my personal account and got only one post. Looks like this behaviour is specific for my "test" accounts ("User"1 and "User2").